# java - msvcr100.dll missing error

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, javafx-2

I was trying to install the java desktop app in 64 bit windows 7 machine then i got the following error. It was resolved by adding the jre path(C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin) to the path variable in the system variables section. Why system doesn't set the java runtime automatically? Is any other solution to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to start the JVM from another program— are you sure this other program (“ABS Client Software”) is a 64 Bit Software?

Comment: ABS Client Software is a 64 bit software. I already installed in the 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM normally doesn’t need the path to be set up- the java launch tool(s) will take care of it. But if an application starts the JVM by itself using a different way, e.g. by loading the `jvm.dll` manually, it has to care about setting the paths. So it’s not the JRE’s fault if this application requires you to set up the path.

Comment: How do we know the application start the JVM by itself?

Comment: You can try to find out using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). With this tool you can see the program’s activities including which way to start the JVM is used.